# Export Multiple Azure AD group members

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory, office365

I am using below code snippet, Instead of -ALL I am trying to pass specific ObjectId or filter group name but getting below error. pls help to fix this.

$groups=Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId "Group1" **- Works fine with one but not with multiple ObjectId**

$groups=Get-AzureADGroup -filter{Name -like "ABC*"} - **Get-AzureADGroup : Cannot evaluate parameter 'Filter'**

```
    Connect-AzureAD
    $groups=Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
    $resultsarray =@()
    ForEach ($group in $groups){
        $members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true 
        ForEach ($member in $members){
           $UserObject = new-object PSObject
           $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Group Name" -Value $group.DisplayName
           $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "Member Name" -Value $member.DisplayName
           $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "ObjType" -Value $member.ObjectType
           $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserType" -Value $member.UserType
           $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserPrinicpalName" -Value $member.UserPrincipalName
           $resultsarray += $UserObject
        }
    }
    $resultsarray | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8  -Delimiter ";" -Path "C:\scripts\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: according to the MSDocs site, the `-Filter` parameter requires a STRING, not a SCRIPTBLOCK. this >>> `[-Filter <String>]` <<< is from here >>> Get-AzureADGroup (AzureAD) | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroup?view=azureadps-2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$groups=Get-AzureADGroup -All
$result=new-object system.colletions.arraylist

foreach($group in $groups)
{
    $members=$group.members
    foreach($member in $members)
    {
        $result.add(
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                "Group Name"=$group.DisplayName
                "Member Name"=$member.DisplayName
                "ObjType"=$member.ObjectType
                "UserType"=$member.UserType
                "UserPrinicpalName"=$member.UserPrincipalName
        }) > $null
    }
}
```

If you wanna search for a specific group you can use `-SearchString 'groupName'` or a list of groups:

```
$groups='group1,group2,group3'.split(',')|%{
    Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString $_
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. If you tell me what you have as input for `Get-AzureADGroup` there is probably a more efficient way to perform the search than foreach-object (pretty inefficient).

Comment: its Azure Security groups, names starts with few same alphabet.

Comment: Ok, I see, so honestly I don't remember if -Filter for AzureAD cmdlets supports wildcard searchs but what I do know is that -Filter expects an expression as a string. Also, Name is not actually an Azure AD attribtue, what you know as Name on AD on premise is translated to 'DisplayName' on Azure AD. So supposing wildcard works, the search for AzureAD groups should be `Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName like 'ABC*'"` if wildcard is not supported then you can do `(Get-AzureADGroup -All).where({$_.DisplayName -like 'ABC*'})`.